Best/simplest method to protect files loaded by html webpage
Assuming one wanted to load a .html webpage on a server, and make it readable from the internet, via web browser, to a limited number of people.
The .html page "reads" some data from a .csv file and plots some graphs and tables from this data.
Assuming one wanted to allow the readers to see the graphs and the tables, but not to be able to download the data contained in the .csv file because it has value (it's research data).
Research on this topic shows that encrypting or obfuscating the code of an html is a waste of time: a skilled person could find a way to read the file, so one cannot embed the .csv data in the html and encrypt the html, that method is off the table.
Server side processing should be safe, but seems quite complicated to implement.
Is there any other method that would be safe and guarantee the protection of the .csv file content?
Changing the .csv file to another format if needed (json, etc.) is doable.
Any suggestion pointing in the right direction would be very appreciated. Thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because this is not specifically about cryptography. For general questions about security please use [security.se]. However, for that the question needs to be specific and contain enough detail. For instance, just focus on access to particular users. "To a limited number of people" is not specific enough; what people, how many etc. General research on access control strategies is recommended.

Two methods spring to mind:-

Convert the charts and tables to raster images like .png files.
Server side processing is not that hard.  You may be familiar with Python. Spin up a microservice, Tomcat or Flask instance that serves   the .csv data as a HTTP response, then consume it with a chart library like Zingchart.  Finally add an IP rule to only allow access from 127.0.0.1.  An example is here.

Not cryptography in the strictest sense though...
